# polarArea Chart.js starting from zero

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Does anyone know how I can get my polar area chart to start from zero, I'm having some difficulty with representing data where one is much larger than the other because the smaller one gets minimized.

Comment: The usage example shows the `beginAtZero` option in use: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html?h=start

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch that!

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are asking for the `startAngle` option of Chart.js that can be found here: [Polar Area GitBook](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html#global-chart-configuration)

> Config Options
>
> These are the customization options specific to Polar Area charts. These options are merged with the global chart configuration options, and form the options of the chart.

startAngle - Starting angle to draw arcs for the first item in a dataset.

```
new Chart(ctx, {
data: data,
type: 'polarArea',
options: startAngle: -Math.PI / 4
});
```

This code will produce the starting angle for the first value in the dataset as 0.785

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax is invalid.